# htaccess is not able to redirect article id to article slug generated with php slug function

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url, slug

There are many question I followed which is posted in stackoverflow but was not helpful for me, thats why i'm trying exactly according to my requirements. Thanks for accepting..

I'm trying from long time but my problem not solved till now. The problem is i'm trying to bring my url seo friendly, like , `example.com/articles.php?id=''` to `example.com/articles/my-first-article`, while slug is generated with php and inserted into database as bellow.

```
function php_slug($string){

                        $spl_char = '/[^\-\s\pN\pL]+/u';
                        $double_char = '/[\-\s]+/';

                        $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', strtolower($string));
                        $slug = preg_replace($double_char, '-', $string);

                        $slug = trim($string, '-');

                        return $slug;
                    }
```

and include in HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-1

#RewriteRule ^/?$ /1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^article([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ article.php?article_link=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^article([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/ article.php?article_link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and linked as

```
<a href="article/?article_link='<?php echo $article_link;?>'">BTN</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, move up your article rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article\/(.*)$ article.php?article_link=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Change your hrefs to preety links (rewrite should catch them):

```
<a href="article/<?php echo $article_link;?>">BTN</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. this method redirect me to http://localhost/cloud-soft/article/index.php, and error message is "This Page isn't working, redirected you too many times"

Comment: Could you show BTN href link (rendered in browser, not php $article_link)?

Comment: thats working fine, but not getting content from article page. https://ibb.co/VgWnSHk  screenshot attached, thanks